# php - calculating distance divded by time

Tags: php, performance, average

How do I divide a decimal by time queried from database as time format.

Any idea?

```
$time = date($entity->getTime()->format('H:i:s'));
$speed = $distance/$time
```

Which is definitely wrong and if my time is 00:40:00, I get some division by zero error.

I am unable to convert it to seconds because php takes DateTime from Time format in database.

Comment: What exactly is "time queried from database"? Why do you say your method (please show it) is "a disaster"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose that you get your time in seconds, but you need to convert minutes and hours to seconds.

```
$seconds = date($entity->getTime()->format('s'));
$minutes = date($entity->getTime()->format('i'));
$hours = date($entity->getTime()->format('h'));
$time = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
$speed = $distance/$time;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I would like to share that format('H') is suppose to be caps for hours. Correct me if I'm wrong. To convert from KM/S to KM/H, multiply *3600 of the speed. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout strtotime() to convert it to seconds.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

**1) Get time in seconds**

```
function time2seconds($time='00:00:00')
{
    list($hours, $mins, $secs) = explode(':', $time);
    return ($hours * 3600 ) + ($mins * 60 ) + $secs;
}

$time = date($entity->getTime()->format('H:i:s'));
$timeInSeconds = time2seconds($time);
$distance = 40000;
$speed = $distance/$timeInSeconds;
```

**2) If you are using MySQL database use function** [`TIME_TO_SEC(time)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

Answer (score 0):

With `strtotime` it is a little bit tricky and only goes to `24:59:59`.
Else use Voitcus solution.

```
$time = '00:40:00';
echo strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = date($entity->getTime()->format('H:i:s'));
$speed = $distance/$time
```

It's wrong. You must do:

```
$speed = $distance/$time * 3.6;
```

For instance this equation is valid `30km/H = 30000m * 3600 seconds * 3.6`